# Making a custom exception more descriptive

Tags: c#, .net, exception

The `Message` property is descriptive but when we throw a JsonRpcException, for ex.`tcs.SetException(new JsonRpcException(response))`, it's flat. How do I make it more descriptive, just like the Message property is?

[image]

```cs
public class JsonRpcException : Exception
{
    public JsonRpcException(JsonRpcResponse<object> response)
    {
        Response = response;
    }

    public JsonRpcResponse<object> Response { get; }

    public override string Message
    {
        get
        {
            if (Response.Error != null)
            {
                return $"{Response.Error.Message} | Code: {Response.Error.Code} | Data: {Response.Error.Data}";
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not check for `Response` being null. Could this be the case? You should definitely do so at least in your Message-Overload.

Comment: ^^ Maybe try `if( Response?.Error != null )` ( or in recent versions: `is not null`) and instead of string.Empty return something like "Response was null".